# linuxpam-pam unix-security-bypass

Tags: linux, privilege-escalation, pam

https://exchange.xforce.ibmcloud.com/vulnerabilities/31739

> linuxpam-pamunix-security-bypass (31739)   reported Jan 23, 2007
>
> Linux-PAM could allow a remote attacker to bypass security
> restrictions, caused by a vulnerability in pam_unix.so when handling
> password hashes that consist of two characters. An attacker could
> exploit this vulnerability to bypass security restrictions and gain
> unauthorized access to the system using arbitrary accounts.
>
> Consequences: Gain Access

Can someone please explain to me how to actually implement this exploit?

I am currently working on HTB cache and I've gained RCE to EMR application. I've
gained access to /var/lib/pam which shows the following:
[image]
[image]

Will these be of any use to me? I'm trying to gain root/user access.

Comment: Personally, I'd first gain a reverse shell before doing anything else. Once a reverse shell is obtained, (assuming the EMR app is not run as root) there might be many ways to escalate your privileges.

Comment: @Jeroen : yes I have a reverse shell as well. PrivEsc is pretty new to me so Im just grasping at straws right now. From what people have mentioned somehow cache is going to play a role in the escalation. But thanks for the suggestion

Comment: _"pam_unix.so in Linux-PAM 0.99.7.0 allows context-dependent attackers to log into accounts whose password hash, as stored in /etc/passwd or /etc/shadow, has only two characters."_ -[nvd](https://nvd.nist.gov/vuln/detail/CVE-2007-0003). Do you have any reason to believe the password hash is 2 characters?

Comment: @multithr3at3d - I don't. Thanks for the effort in replying